# What is $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n^x})^n$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I am calculating the value of $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n^x})^n$, where $x>0$. Here is my idea: let $z=n^x$, then $z$ tends to infinity as $n$ tends to infinity. Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n^x})^n=\lim_{z\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}{z})^{\log_{x}{z}}=\lim_{z\to\infty}((1-\frac{1}{z})^z)^\frac{\log_{x}z}{z}=\lim_{z\to\infty}(e^{-1})^0=1$$.
 I'm not sure if the second to last equality holds.

Thanks for leablood's comment, I made a mistake. If $z=n^x$, then $n=z^{1/x}$.

Comment: if $z = n^x$ than $n \ne log_x z$.  $n = z^{\frac 1 x}$.

Comment: if x<1,(1-1/n^x)^(n^x)*(n^a) where a+x =1, you can make (1-1/n^x)^(n^x) close to 1/e for big n, then rising power to n^a you can it goes to zero

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake. Then the result will coincide with Joseph's answer, which depends on $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Your equalities are wrong.

What you should do instead is:

$$(1-\frac 1{n^x})^n=e^{n\log(1-1/n^x)}.$$

Then use the fact that

$$\log(1+x)\underset{x\to 0}{\sim}x.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(1-n^{-x})^n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-n^{-x})^k=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{(1-\frac{1}{n})…(1-\frac{k-1}{n})}{k!}(-n^{1-x})^k\approx e^{-n^{1-x}}$$

Put in a value for $x$ and let be $n\to\infty$ . Check this for $0<x<1$, $x=1$ and $x>1$ .

Answer (score 0):

The log of the limit is $\frac{log(1-n^{-x})}{\frac{1}{n}}$. So using l'hopital, we have $\frac{xn^{-(x+1)}}{1-n^{-x}} \cdot -n^2$ which becomes $\frac{-xn}{n^x-1}$, differentiating again makes it clear that the log of the limit approaches zero. Therefore the limit approaches $1$ in most cases.

Note that the log of the limit becomes $\frac{-1}{n^{x-1}}$, so if $x>1$, the limit tends to $0$. If $1>x$, the limit tends to $-\infty$, suggesting that the limit in question is $1$ at $x> $ or equal to $1$.

Comment: Calculation of derivative of $\log(1-n^{-x})$ is wrong.

Comment: corrected, i think

Answer (score 0):

when n is large enough ${((1-1/n^x)^{n^x}})^{n^{1-x}}\approx (1/e)^{n^{1-x}}$,  you can see it converges to 0, 1/e and 1 for appropriate values of x

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the function instead of the sequence, which gives more flexibility. Taking the logarithm and setting set $u=1/t$, the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}t\log\left(1-\frac{1}{t^x}\right)=
\lim_{u\to0^+}\frac{\log(1-u^x)}{u}
$$
With l'Hôpital,
$$
\lim_{u\to0^+}\frac{-xu^{x-1}}{1-u^x}=
\begin{cases}
-\infty & \text{if $0<x<1$}\\
-1 & \text{if $x=1$} \\
0 & \text{if $x>1$}
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore, taking the exponential,
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{t^x}\right)^t=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $0<x<1$}\\
e^{-1} & \text{if $x=1$} \\
1 & \text{if $x>1$}
\end{cases}
$$